# Can Ajax Action [add_action('wp_ajax_{action_name}', '{action_name}'] be hooked into wp hook

Tags: ajax

Just curious - whether AJAX Action can be hooked into `wp` hook?
For Example:
`add_action( 'wp', array( 'MyAjaxRegistrarClass', 'ajax_registrar' ) );`

```
// MyAjaxRegistrarClass
class MyAjaxRegistrarClass{

    public static function ajax_registrar() {       
        MyAnotherClass::fn_register_ajax();
        //Call fn_register_ajax of other classes here
    }
}//Class Ends here

// MyAnotherClass
class MyAnotherClass {

    public static function fn_register_ajax() {     
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_testing_ajax', array(__CLASS__, 'testing_ajax' ) );
    }   

    public static function testing_ajax() {     
        echo 'Success!'.__FUNCTION__.' was called from '.__CLASS__;     
        die();
    }   
}
```

Any pointer? Of-course, there are many options for Ajax Hooks. Just curious to know whether this can be done or not.

Comment: I don't even _remember_ there being `wp` hook, what exactly do you want to achieve with it and for what purpose? :)

Comment: There is indeed a wp hook (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp), but I don't know whyy you'd want to do this?

Comment: I just wanted to register my ajax actions after WP object has been created. Because after WP I can identify post/page based on which I would register ajax actions. 
Note: I wanted to register ajax actions only when a particular page/custom post type post loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not! My design goal was to automate the creation of related objects while performing ajax options. However, I have modified it to automate the same task differently.

- Now all ajax functions in my classes are static.
- JavaScript captures the class name and function name where the ajax processing will happen (as these are provided as JavaScript variables programmatically) and send the same with ajax post/get.
- Get/Post data gets captured by a universal ajax processor and determines which class::function to call.

So, considering this, all I have to do is create just one ajax_action hook for my universal ajax processor.